# Phone Contacts With PHP

Tags: php, mobile, contacts

Is there a way for me to access a users phone contact like from a nokia phone using PHP? I want to build a mobile website that can get the users phone book.

Comment: Is it me or does this sound very dodgy?

Comment: @Chris not necessarily, I can think of a number of legitimate use cases. But it's not possible anyway, so no problem :)

Comment: @Pekka you are probably correct. Maybe my general mistrust of getting users 'address book, credit card, ssn et al'

Comment: @Thief that has nothing to do with anything. The OP has been asking a number of totally legitimate mobile programming questions

Comment: @ThiefMaster, no disrespect, have u looked at your username, you are not serious. @All It's actually an application that is suppose to help the user send an SMS to users on his contact list. Thank you.

Comment: Would this be more effective than sending SMS, normally, through your phone ui?

Comment: @sshow, well different operators have different tariff for sending SMS, so the app is to create a unify place for sending sms for a flat rate.

Answer (score 2):

PHP doesn't run on the user's phone, it runs on your server.

What you are looking to do is impossible in PHP, and due to security restrictions, probably impossible for web sites to do in general.

Comment: [PHP can run on mobile phones](http://derickrethans.nl/talks/phpinside-ipc10.pdf). It takes a ton of effort though and whether doing so would allow you to access the phonebook is yet another question.

Comment: @Gordon yeaaahh... But  it probably isn't what he means.

Comment: I know, just saying PHP can run on mobiles. I've seen it. It feels like an abomination, but at the same time it's pretty cool.

Comment: @Gordon I guess that sums it up pretty well :) Interesting though. I could see some serious uses for simple tasks. But then, there's probably better languages for that on mobile platforms

Answer (score 1):

**It is not possible.**

Actually, it would be horrible if that was possible. PHP is running on the remote webserver, so it cannot access your contacts at all.

Even JavaScript (which runs on the client) is not able to access things like that which is also good since it would be able to submit them to a random server withour you knowing about it...